# Javascript/jQuery optimization for large projects (social media)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a social media website of the scale of LinkedIn, and I am struggling with few things related to JS. As project is going on, the requirement of JavaScript/jQuery is increasing. I am guessing by the end of the project, jQuery required on each page will be of average file size 1.5MB which is a bad idea. Functions like image upload, comments, like, updates is almost on every page.

My Question here is **How to optimize jQuery? Any tricks or concept that I can use on this project which will lower file size as well as do these functions (there are much more than just above ones)?**

Here I have already implemented:
1. Compress/Minify jQuery by PHP plugin
2. Use `jQuery.getScript()` to load file only when it required
3. Divide one large JS file into few separate files to finish loading faster
4. HTML optimization (Google Pagespeed)

Comment: This question would be better suited for [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you tried automatic js minification on server side?

Comment: yeah. https://github.com/tedious/JShrink

Comment: I was thinking on Apache side, something like https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-js-minify (I haven't tried it).

Comment: @cakan should be obvious by now that this issue is not about minification, rather a dependency per page type and structural issue

Comment: @cakan, I have actually implemented that :)

Comment: I am looking for concepts that I am not familiar with. If something   like jQuery helper plugin which help manage js file to add/remove when it requires. I mean realistic apart from my Sci-Fi Ideas :)

Comment: Should actually find some good articles on subject of loading. I've seen a few lately discussing some advanced loading techniques. Here's one I had stored might be helpful http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/ Also look into `Above the fold loading` .. basically deferring what wouldn't be in viewport until after page load

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of people using YUI Compressor, which 'has a better compression ratio' than most other tools. Not sure what you're using for compression at the moment, but this could provide a slight improvement. http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CDN (Content Delivery Network)](http://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/) to deliver jQuery. The browser will most probably cache the library and each page that loads, won't actually be needing to download the library again. This, if i'm not wrong, is one of the main reasons CDN's are used.

Otherwise, you should rethink your dependency/development strategy since [you might not need jquery after all](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) on each page. At least not whole of it.